# Asymptotic law in Laplace's problem

Tags: differential-equations, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

$\textbf{Eigenvalue problem on a unit square $\Omega =  [0,1]^2$
:}$

Consider the eigenvalue problem with the Dirichlet boundary condition that is,

$$-Lu = \lambda u$$
where $$L = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$$

The boundary condition is $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$.

I have calculated the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of this eigenvalue problem. Now, I am looking for $\textbf{Weyl's Law}$. We know that eigenvalues of above said problem form an increasing sequence $$0 = \lambda_{0} < \lambda_{1} \leq \lambda _{2} \leq \cdots$$ and that satisfy $\textbf{Weyl asymptotic law}$ $$N(t) = \#\{\lambda_{j} \leq t\}$$ Therefore, $N(t)$  finds the numbers eigenvalues less than or equal to $t$ (counted with multiplicity). Also,for more details please see the wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_law).

I am looking for $\textbf{Weyl's Law}$ in Mathematica and how to compute the numbers of eigenvalues less than or equal to $t$.

Thanking in advanced.

Comment: At the present `DSolve[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == \[Lambda]*u[x, y], u[x, 0] == 0,
   u[x, 1] == 0, u[0, y] == 0, u[1, y] == 0}, u[x, y], {x, y}]` finds only zero solution. I think the situation will not change in the foreseeable future. I have strong doubts concerning a closed-form expression for the eigenvalues.

Comment: `DSolve[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == -2*Pi^2*u[x, y], u[x, 0] == 0, 
   u[x, 1] == 0, u[0, y] == 0, u[1, y] == 0}, u[x, y], {x, y}] 
 ]` outputs `u[x, y] -> 0`. I think the eigenvalues are implemented as table values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For eigenvalues of a unit square region you could e.g. define:

```
Clear[n];
n[t_] := n[t] = (c = 0; 
   While[DEigenvalues[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
        DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
       u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[], c + 1][[-1]] < t, c++];
    c)
```

The first 5 eigenvalues are:

```
DEigenvalues[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
 u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[], 5]
```

[image]

Using `n` from above:

n[5 Pi^2]

n[8 Pi^2]

n[10 Pi^2]

(* 1,3,4*)

Answer (score 3):

Starting from the [analytic solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240086/26598) and speeding it up a bit, here is a function to calculate the multiplicities of the eigenvalues $\lambda/\pi^2=k\in \{1\ldots n\}$,

```
S[n_Integer?Positive] := 
  BinCounts[Plus @@@ Tuples[Range[Sqrt[n]]^2, 2], {1, n + 1}]
```

and the cumulative number of states with eigenvalues $\lambda/\pi^2\le k\in \{1\ldots n\}$,

```
T[n_Integer?Positive] := Accumulate[S[n]]
```

Test:

```
T[10]
(*    {0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6}    *)
```

Least-squares fitting these results for $k\in\{1\ldots10^5\}$

```
Fit[T[10^5], {k, Sqrt[k], 1}, k]
(*    0.785396*k - 0.999144*Sqrt[k] + 0.583841    *)
```

which I have refined using $k\in\{1\ldots10^9\}$ to the approximation

```
a[k_] = π/4 * k - Sqrt[k] + 0.643;
```

where the last term is a bit uncertain and I don't have an exact expression. Weyl's law is then approximately

```
a[λ/π^2]
(*    λ/(4π) - Sqrt[λ]/π + 0.643    *)
```

Visual test with $k\in\{1\ldots10^5\}$: the difference between the exact values of `T[10^5]` and the approximate values `a[k]` seem to oscillate around zero,

```
With[{n = 10^5},
  t = T[n];
  DiscretePlot[t[[k]] - a[k], {k, n}, PlotRange -> 30 {-1, 1}]]
```

[image]